# parse xml data in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I have a xml string comming form the web server as below

```
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <doLoginResponse xmlns="http://login.mss.uks.com">
    <doLoginReturn>
      <errorCode>IPH_I_LGN_002</errorCode>
      <errorMsg>Logged in sucessfully</errorMsg>
      <number>13733479454157901</number>
    </doLoginReturn>
  </doLoginResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I would like to parse the xml string and would like to print the errorCode, errorMsg, number . How I can I do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to access the elements in your XML. Following code will print *errorCode*, *errorMsg* and *number* elements in a MessageBox:

```cs
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("Your XML string");
    var errorCode = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("errorCode", "http://login.mss.uks.com")).FirstOrDefault();
    var errorMsg = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("errorMsg", "http://login.mss.uks.com")).FirstOrDefault();
    var number = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("number", "http://login.mss.uks.com")).FirstOrDefault();

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error code: {0}\nMessage: {1}\nNumber: {2}", errorCode.Value, errorMsg.Value, number.Value));
```

This will show a MessageBox with following content:

> Error code: IPH_I_LGN_002
>      Message: Logged in sucessfully
>      Number: 13733479454157901

Comment: I am getting null string in the errorCode, errorMsg, number. That's during showing the message application crashed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize about namespaces. I have completed the answer. It should work now.

Comment: @Rajesh accessing elements follwoing way: `var errorCode = doc.Descendants("{http://login.mss.uks.com}errorCode").FirstOrDefault();` would work too